# -fallbackfee option in sendtoaddress

Tags: transaction-fees, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli, fee-estimation

I'm trying to send some bitcoins using bitcoin-cli API, but bitcoin core tells me that Fallbackfee is disabled. How can I set a value for fallbackfee? 
I've tried to specify it like
 *bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress -fallbackfee=someValue* but it didn't work.
 I've also set **true** for *substractfeefromamount* and **false** for *replaceable*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seem like you tried to run fallbackfee in the terminal ? fallbackfee is a configuration option and should be put inside a bitcoin.conf file, if you dont have this file on your bitcoin directory you can create it: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File

Then add your `fallbackfee=someValue` (without the -) inside your bitcoin.conf file on a new line then restart your bitcoin client and try your command again.

Answer (score 6):

Another option that works for me is to call the `settxfee` with amount before calling `sendtoaddress`.