# Sending regtest Bitcoin fails with an error message. How do I resolve this error?

Tags: transaction-fees, bitcoin-core-development, regtest, signet

When I try to send regtest Bitcoin using bitcoin-cli:

```
./bitcoin-cli -regtest sendtoaddress bc1q09vm5lfy0j5reeulh4x5752q25uqqvz34hufdl 0.1
```

I get the error message:

```
error code: -6
error message:
Fee estimation failed. Fallbackfee is disabled. Wait a few blocks or enable -fallbackfee.
```

How do I resolve this so I can send regtest Bitcoin?

Comment: I think it was already addressed in https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/97174/using-bitcoin-client-and-bitcoind-for-regtest-error-regarding-fallback-fees/97223#97223 ?

Comment: Thanks, darosior. Voted to close this one.

Answer (score 1):

You could enable `-fallbackfee` as it says in the error message but the easiest or quickest way to resolve this is to set a fee. In this example we are setting a fee of 1 satoshis per byte.

```
./bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress "bc1q09vm5lfy0j5reeulh4x5752q25uqqvz34hufdl" 0.1 "" "" false true 1 sat/B
```

If you do

```
./bitcoin-cli -regtest help sendtoaddress
```

you will see what those arguments after the regtest address represent.

Alternatively if you want to set the fallback fee see this StackExchange [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91533/fallbackfee-option-in-sendtoaddress).

This PR [16524](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/16524) merged in October 2019 disabled `-fallbackfee` across all chains (mainnet, testnet, regtest) by default.